# How to create an X++ batch job in Axapta 3.0?

Tags: axapta, x++

I'd like to create a batch job in X++ for Microsoft Axapta 3.0 (Dynamics AX).

How can I create a job which executes an X++ function like this one?

```
static void ExternalDataRead(Args _args)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the bare minimum needed to create a batch job in AX:

Create a batch job by creating a new class that extends the `RunBaseBatch` class:

```
class MyBatchJob extends RunBaseBatch
{
}
```

Implement the abstract method `pack()`:

```
public container pack()
{
    return connull();
}
```

Implement the abstract method `unpack()`:

```
public boolean unpack(container packedClass)
{
    return true;
}
```

Override the `run()` method with the code you want to execute:

```
public void run()
{
    ;
    ...
    info("MyBatchJob completed");
}
```

Add a static `main` method to your class to create an instance of your class and call the standard `RunBaseBatch` dialog:

```
static void main(Args _args)
{
    MyBatchJob myBatchJob = new MyBatchJob();
    ;
    if(myBatchJob.prompt())
    {
        myBatchJob.run();
    }
}
```

If you want your batch job to have a description in the batch list, add a static `description` method to your class:

```
server client static public ClassDescription description()
{
    return "My batch job";
}
```