# Ax 4.0 X++: Run a class when a file is created in a folder

Tags: x++

How is it possible to make a function in Ax 4.0 that will monitor a local Windows folder and run a class when a new file is detected inside this folder?

I'm unable to find anything that will guide me in the right direction, using Google and forum searches, when it comes to X++ and in particular the older Ax 4.0 my customer is running.

Background for this issue is that we recieve a xml file from a web front end and need to create a quotation based on this file. The class reading the xml file and creating a quotation is already up and running in Ax 4.0, but for now I need to manually trigger the class to run.

Comment: Try creating a batch process to verify if file exists in a folder and call your process there. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa549082(v=ax.10).aspx

Comment: Another blog on batch process https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axstart/archive/2014/02/13/ax-3-0-and-4-0-batching

Comment: Refer this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170088/how-to-create-an-x-batch-job-in-axapta-3-0